# FirebaseStorage upload does not work on Flutter web build

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I need to upload fotos via an webapp to firestore. If I try it on thge debug version with "flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit" it works.

If I export it and try it on the web. Hostet on the same firebase project.
with "flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit" it does not work.

```
Future<void> _uploadImage() async {
    FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('$id/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}_1.png')
        .putData(_imageFile!);
  }



  var _uploadTask;
  Uint8List? _imageFile;

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    Uint8List? pickedImage =
        await ImagePickerWeb.getImageAsBytes().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = value;
      });
    });
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = pickedImage;
        print(_imageFile);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Firebase Storage (or Cloud Storage) and Firestore are two quite different products. Since you're uploading files here, you're actually using Cloud/Firebase Storage. Please tag accordingly going forward, as it increase the chances that people with the right knowledge to help will see your question.